# SQL php modal form

Tags: php, jquery

Hello im trying to use a modal form to insert a simple data name into sql.

im testing this by trying this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            echo "deu";
        }
        ?>
```

just to test if button works and when i open window it alreaddy show the echo before i click the button...

here is the code i so far have:

button to open window:

```
<button class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal">Novo grupo</button>
```

window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalHorizontal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" 
               data-dismiss="modal">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   <span class="sr-only">Fechar</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                A criar novo grupo...
            </h4>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-body">


              <div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"for="inputEmail3">Nome</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    placeholder="Nome do Grupo"/>
                </div>
              </div>


        </div>

        <!-- Modal Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Fechar
            </button>

            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                Criar
            </button>
        </div>
        <?php if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            echo "deu";
        }
        ?>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `!isset()` means "Is not set".  If you only want to display "deu" if the button has been pressed then you need to remove the exclamation point.

Comment: tryed it...happens same thing... when i click the button to open window(modal), its alreaddy there. [link](http://prntscr.com/bsin6b)